# Passing properties from class to base class

Tags: php, oop, properties

In my program an object represents one row in database, it has all the same data and setters & getters etc.

Each column's value is saved to a property within the object. For example:

```
class Person extends Base {
  protected $name;
  protected $age;

  /* Setters & Getters */
}
```

On the Base class I have a Save() method that will create an update query out of the properties on the Person class. I'm having trouble figuring out how to pass the properties to the Base's Save() method. I have few in mind but I'm not too happy with them.

1.
Add prefix for all properties. Like "db_":

```
protected $db_id;
protected $db_age;

Loop get_object_vars($this) and check the prefix.
```

- Confusing
- Ugly

2.
Add an array that contains all the property names that are related to the row in the database

```
protected $db_properties = array("id", "age");
protected $id;
protected $age;

Loop get_object_vars($this) and check if they are in the $db_properties array.
Or loop the $db_properties and get the properties.
```

- Double identical data

3.
Assume that all properties are always related to the row in the database.

```
Loop get_object_vars($this).
```

- Can't add properties for other stuff

Is there some other way to do this?

Comment: Well this is a good place for a polymorphism. I don't know if there's a clean way to do exactly what you want. When I had to implement similar functionality using another program language I just defined the `save()` method as virtual and then override it where I need to.

Comment: [Use annotations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-column).

Comment: Is that a part of PHP ORM that the OP is using?

Comment: Like @Leron suggests, I'd create an abstract method in `Base`, and override it in each derived class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood the question, but have you considered a dictionary?
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: this is not an answer

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need to pass it back to `Base` tho? When you instantiate `Person`, `Base` becomes a part of that. So if `Base` defines a variable, `Person` will also have that variable.

Comment: Well, maybe I used a bad choice of words. Anyways the problem is that when the Save() method is inherited from the Base and I call it, how does it know which properties are related to the database row. For example the $name and $age are but if I add a new property for the class that's not related to the row in the database, I don't want the Save() function try to add those to the query.

Comment: If you need more options passed to your function, why not pass an array as a parameter and make your save function just add those fields to the query?